# Does the series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \lbrack {\sqrt\frac{n}{2}} \rbrack$ Converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Does the series:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \lbrack {\sqrt\frac{n}{2}} \rbrack$ Converge ?

Note: by the brackets I mean the floor function.

I tried to substitute numbers and look at the members of the sum, and I got something like this: $0, 1, -1, 1 , -2, 2 ........ -k,k...$ I don't think the sum of these numbers will lead any where, and the series diverges but I don't know to to prove this mathematically. any kind of help would be appreciable.

Comment: the general term does not converge to 0 so the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Given the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n
$$
the necessary condition for convergence is: 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0
$$
but that's not your case.

Showing this is enough to prove formally the divergence of the series.

Comment: @r9m If $a_n$ is not a decreasing sequence, the alternating series could still diverge even if $a_n\to 0$. http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tvogel/gallery/node9.html

Comment: @r9m Also note that there are alternating sequences with $a_n$  that are not monotonically decreasing with $a_n\to0$, and yet converge.  Either way, the "iff" statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Braindead ah! right you are! I should have written converges if $a_n \to 0$ monotonically.